# Read excel files from a folder, extract a cell from sheet-1 and append values to a new excel sheet

Tags: python, excel

I have around 100 excel files in a folder. I need to extract a cell, say name column `D6` from  the sheet-1 of the excel files and output the same to  a new excel file/sheet. I have a followed a few SO questions but have not been able to find the desired output. This is what my issue is when I run the below program`

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate a non-NDFrame object
```

`

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import xlrd
import xlwt

files = os.listdir(path)
files


all_data = pd.DataFrame()

for file in files:
    wb = xlrd.open_workbook(file)
    sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
    df = sheet.cell_value(5,3)
    all_data.append(df,ignore_index=True)

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
all_data.to_excel(writer,'sheet1')
writer.save()
```

Comment: If you get stuck with using pandas to for working with excel, I suggest to try working with excel files with the pywin32 package

Answer (score 0):

Your error says that you can only concat a dataframe with another dataframe. when you read the cell with `xlrd` you don't get a df-object. so either make the single cell a dataframe or store it temorarily and make the dataframe afterwards.

something like this (untested) should do it.

```
all_data = [] # list
for file in files:
    df = pd.read_excel(file, sheetname='sheet-1')
    all_data.append(df.iloc[5,3])
all_data = pd.DataFrame(all_data) # dataframe
all_data.to_excel('all_data.xlsx')
```

or one could use other libraries as well to make the same, like openpyxl for example.